# SQL: OPENROWSET, can't build for the request string?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to construct the query used with the OPENROWSET method.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM
OPENROWSET
('SQLOLEDB', 'srv'; 'login'; 'mdp';
'SELECT *
 FROM Case
 WHERE ID = ' + @caseID)
```

But when I do that I get the error: **Incorrect Syntax near '+'**

How can I build the query?
Thank

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although the query in `OPENROWSET` is specified as a string and by that means looks very much like a dynamic query, the syntax does not allow it to be constructed likewise, out of parts.

I'm afraid, you'll have to build a dynamic query, which will call `OPENROWSET`, something like this:

```
SET @sql = '
  SELECT *
  FROM
  OPENROWSET
  (''SQLOLEDB'', ''srv''; ''login''; ''mdp'';
   ''SELECT *
     FROM Case
     WHERE ID = ' + @caseID + ''')';
EXEC(@sql);
```