# pass dynamic file path of excel to "OPENROWSET"

Tags: sql-server-2005, openrowset

I want pass dynamic URL of excel to "OPENROWSET".

NOTE - I am passing returned result of excel file to cursor.
I want to pass file path to "@excelpath",
I have tried many ways but its giving syntax error.

```
 ALTER procedure [dbo].[import_excel]
(
    @excelpath as nvarchar(max)
)
as      
begin
  set nocount on 
  DECLARE insert_cursor CURSOR FOR 
  select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 
    'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\memberdata.xlsx', [Sheet1$])
  OPEN insert_cursor;
  FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor
      INTO @id_number, @memberName

  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
  -- body of cursor
      FETCH NEXT FROM insert_cursor
      INTO @id_number, @memberName
  END
  CLOSE insert_cursor;
  DEALLOCATE insert_cursor;
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build your query using dynamic SQL, as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935598/sql-openrowset-cant-build-for-the-request-string). It would probably be simplest for you to insert the data from your query into a permanent table, then run the cursor over the permanent table. In that way you minimize the amount of SQL you need to work with dynamically.