# using Sql Server OPENROWSET with Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, openrowset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [pass dynamic file path of excel to “OPENROWSET”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11683338/pass-dynamic-file-path-of-excel-to-openrowset)

my mind is currently out of order as I really cannot underestand what's wrong with my stored procedure definition. why OPENROWSET does not accept dynamic parameters.

this code just put a Red error line approx. everywhere !!!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE InsertCellNumbers 
  @filePath NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @cityId INT 
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  declare @provider as nvarchar(30) = 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0';
  declare @databasename as nvarchar(max) = 'Excel 12.0;Database=' + @filePath;
  declare @select as nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]';

  Insert into dbo.IranCellPhoneNumbers
  SELECT codeposti as PostalCode,mobile as Number,CityId
  FROM OPENROWSET(@provider,@databasename,@select);
END
```

I just want to set the filename of an excel file and run the SP to insert for me. I do this because there are lots of excel files to be imported.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic469199-5-1.aspx Apparently, variables cannot be used for `OPENROWSET`, but you can try it with dynamic SQL.

Comment: I agree guys, it was duplicate and you've helped me a lot