# Incorrect syntax near '+' when executing AD search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, active-directory

The following obviously works:

```
declare @Client as varchar(100)

set @Client = 'santos'

SELECT displayName FROM OPENROWSET
    ('ADSDSOObject', 'adsdatasource';'mbbxx\santos';'consultant1', 
     'SELECT displayName FROM ''LDAP://mbbadsrv1/DC=mbbxx,DC=com'' where 
sAMAccountName=''santos''')
```

But when I try to pass a paramater, I get the error

```
declare @Client as varchar(100)

set @Client = 'santos'

SELECT displayName FROM OPENROWSET
    ('ADSDSOObject', 'adsdatasource';'mbbxx\santos';'consultant1', 
     'SELECT displayName FROM ''LDAP://mbbadsrv1/DC=mbbxx,DC=com'' where
sAMAccountName=''' + @Client + '''')
```

What am I doing wrong here? does OPENROWSET follow a specific order or cannot handle parameters? Thanks.

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: OPENROWSET, can't build for the request string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6935598/sql-openrowset-cant-build-for-the-request-string)